# 'Read-only mode' banner on stackexchange.com has overlapping text

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, maintenance

When the site was in readonly mode for maintenance an hour ago, I noticed that the banner on https://stackexchange.com/questions had its text overlapping:

[image: Screenshot of readonly banner]

The issue seems to be that `#system-message` has `line-height: 5px`.

Here's the full-screen screenshot:

[image: Full-screen screenshot]

Chromium (Brave) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Repro here, didn't matter how I adjusted the screen. No-repro on any of the other 8 sites I had open.